# Mover elemento para cima em 50% de seu tamanho

Tags: css, flexbox

Como eu poderia fazer uma sobreposição vertical do Flexbox? Quero fazer com que metade do circulo fique dentro do item acima.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #8844ee;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.background-header { 
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.topo {
  background-color: #1b2b34;
  background-size: cover;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.foto {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  align-self: center;
}

.textos > h1,
.textos > h3{
  display:inline;
}

.textos {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="background-header">
    <header class="topo"></header>
    <section class="foto">
    </section>
    <section class="textos">
      <h1>Nome</h1>
      <h3>23</h3>
      <p>Cidade</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual item acima? O de classe `.topo`?

Comment: esse item é background que fica na parte superior do card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) para *movimentar* o elemento para cima em 50% do seu tamanho. Para isso, utilize o transformador `translateY`, que *move* o elemento no eixo Y.

Então:

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

De modo que:

- `translateY` informa que queremos modificar a posição do elemento no eixo Y;
- `-50%` indica que queremos movimentar o elemento *para cima* em 50% do seu tamanho.

No seu caso:

```css
.foto {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #8844ee;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.background-header { 
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.topo {
  background-color: #1b2b34;
  background-size: cover;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.foto {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  align-self: center;
}

.textos > h1,
.textos > h3{
  display:inline;
}

.textos {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="background-header">
    <header class="topo"></header>
    <section class="foto">
    </section>
    <section class="textos">
      <h1>Nome</h1>
      <h3>23</h3>
      <p>Cidade</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>Coloquei no topo da folha de estilo para ficar mais fácil de encontrar.</sup>

Comment: Ah, o negativo sem explicação, que maravilha! 

Answer (score 2):

Aplicando a propriedade `margin-top` inserindo `-10%` do valor que está posicionado!

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #8844ee;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.background-header { 
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.topo {
  background-color: #1b2b34;
  background-size: cover;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.foto {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: -10%;
}

.textos > h1,
.textos > h3{
  display:inline;
}

.textos {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="background-header">
    <header class="topo"></header>
    <section class="foto">
    </section>
    <section class="textos">
      <h1>Nome</h1>
      <h3>23</h3>
      <p>Cidade</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que o tenha ajudado!

Comment: +1 Sua resposta é muito boa, mas ela funciona se manter o `height` da foto fixo em `75px`, ou seja, ela não se adapta de acordo com o tamanho da foto. Nesse caso a resposta do @LuizFelipe é a que se encaixa melhor :)

Comment: Sim, sim, também concordo, mas como me pareceu um layout que necessariamente não iria ir se ajustando conforme altura e largura da página, a opção seria a mais "válida", mas consequentemente para atualizações futuras de uma tag, a melhor opção é que os demais se ajustem conforme alterações, para não haver dores de cabeça! Obrigado pelo toque  @CmteCardeal